# Check if in array before redirect

Tags: php, arrays

Lets say a visitor types in: user_001, id like the script to see if 001.php is in the array before it redirects the user, or alternatively got to the exit link.

I'm guessing it will involve the **in_array() Function**?

```
<?php
    $exitlink = "error.php";
    $page_name=$_POST['usernumber'];
    $pos=strpos($page_name,"_");
    if($pos==true){
        $valid_ids = array("001.php", "002.php", "003.php");
        $request = substr($page_name, strpos($page_name, "_") + 1);
        header("Location:" . $request . ".php");
    }else {
        header("Location:" . $exitlink);
    }
?>
```

okay so i have listed the array:

```
 $valid_ids = array("001.php", "002.php", "003.php");
```

How do i make the script check if `$request` is in the array before it decides to go to valid .php or `$exitlink`?

Comment: use `in_array()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok guys, thanks to your combined help, i cracked it!

```
<?
$exitlink = "error.php";
$page_name=$_POST['usernumber'];
$pos=strpos($page_name,"_");
$request = substr($page_name, strpos($page_name, "_") + 1);
$valid_ids = array("123", "456", "789");
if(in_array($request, $valid_ids)){
header("Location:" . $request . ".php");
}
else{ 
header("Location: " . $exitlink);
}
?>
```

XD

Answer (score 2):

Nice and simple one, use `in_array()`. Also make sure your valid id's don't contain `.php`, or else you could end up with `{id}.php.php`

```
if(in_array($request, $valid_ids)){
  header("Location: " . $request); //Add ".php" only if the request doesn't have it in it. Or else you'll get Location: 001.php.php
}else{
  header("Location: " . $exitlink);
}
```

EDIT: As for your second addition, if it is always going to be `user_{some number}` You could just use php's replace function to replace `"user_"` with `""` as follows...

```
str_replace("user_", "", $request);
```

EDIT 2:
  Use `explode();`

```
$stringExploded = explode("_", $request);
  $requestId = $stringExploded[1];
```

This changes the string to an array of strings, with each split by the "_"

For example
  `"I_am_a_goat"` would split to `["I", "am", "a", "goat"]` when used with `explode("_", array);`

Comment: ahh yes you're right, my mistake (.php)
how would i keep: $request = substr($page_name, strpos($page_name, "_") + 1); and also check array?

Comment: || !in_array

- maybe this ?

Comment: @jinshun_li Edited original answer (:

Comment: it may change to, superuser, rookieuser, so on so wouldnt work for me :(

Comment: @jinshun_li Edited again to suit your needs (: